# Apple MDM (Mobile Device Management) app - get applications list?

Tags: ios, mdm

I am developing an MDM app. The company is registered as an enterprise account, and we do have a working MDM app.

Now I was asked to add handling the list of installed application, and reporting them to the server.

Searched, but can't find a function (framework) to call to get a list of installed apps on the iPhone device.

Thx

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicemanagement/list_the_installed_apps  Where did you look?

Comment: Thx for replying. Yes I did find that, but unless I misunderstood it - this is a query to a server, not a call to a native function. My situation is that I am developing the (native) iOS app that manages the MDM operations on the iPhone device. Our company server needs to get a list of installed apps, so I need to find a way for my native code to call a function that returns a list of installed apps on that iPhone.

Comment: A native app cannot get the list of installed apps.  In an MDM solution the main purpose of the native app is to authenticate the user and provide the MDM management profile for the user to install.  Pretty much everything else is the server sending messages to the device to have it execute commands.  The native app can do extra things that the MDM protocol can't, such as recording the device location and reporting it to your server